# IFTTT: How to avoid URL shortening in Email-Channel?

Tags: ifttt

We use IFTTT and the new Maker-Event from our local network for various automation tasks. It's a great service and it works.

We have a receipe like

```
IF Maker-Event THEN Email-Channel (Send me an email at xxx@yyy.com)
```

The email body is specified as follows:

```
What: {{EventName}}<br>
{{Value1}}<br>
{{Value2}}<br>
{{Value3}}<br>
When: {{OccurredAt}}<br>
```

This works perfect, but if there is an url given as value, this url is shortened by IFTTT to `http://ift.tt/...` even if our url contains private ip-addresses as `10.0.0.23`.

Unfortunately we don't have internet access at the time the email is read and so the link fails. Is there any chance to avoid url shortening in the Email channel at IFTTT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFTTT provides an option to turn off URL shortening. Go to this url:

```
https://ifttt.com/preferences/settings
```

And change following settings. Just uncheck and you're done.

[image]